# Asyncio example in Python

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to learn native coroutine.
I run the above example and I don't understand it.

Here is the example.

```
import asyncio

async def say_after(delay, what):
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    print(what)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(3, "A")
    )
    
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(
        say_after(2, "B")
    )

    print("----0")
    await task1
    print("----1")
    await task2

asyncio.run(main())
```

I heard that `await` waits for the task to finish.
I expected to be printed in the order

```
A
B
----1
```

However, in the example above, `----1` is output after both `B` and `A` are printed.

The following is the output printed.

```
----0
B
A
----1
```

Why is this output created?

Do you know a site that has a collection of useful examples for studying native coroutine?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what happens on a timeline:

After 0 seconds:

- `task1` starts
- `task2` starts
- output `---0`
- `await task1` blocks

After 2 seconds:

- `task2` prints `B` and finishes

After 3 seconds:

- `task1` prints `A` and finishes
- `await task1` returns
- output `---1`
- `await task2` returns (task was already finished 1 second ago)

Comment: Why ------1 comes at the end? I thought the output should be ----0 ------1 B A. What part am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee in what order the async tasks are run. The only guarantee you have is when you `await` a task execution in `main` will stop until that task is complete. The following are all valid outputs of your program and you can't assume that you will get any one in particular:

```
A
B
----0
----1
```

```
B
A
----0
----1
```

```
----0
A
B
----1
```

```
----0
B
A
----1
```

```
A
----0
B
----1
```

```
B
----0
A
----1
```

```
A
----0
----1
B
```

```
----0
A
----1
B
```

Comment: `---0` will always come before `A` and `B` because the two tasks sleep for 2 or 3 seconds, respectively, while the main function runs. `A` will always come after `B` because task2 wakes up 1 second earlier than task1.

Comment: tbh I don't know if it is *guaranteed* that `sleep(2)` wakes up earlier than `sleep(3)` but I think something would be seriously wrong if it didn't.

Comment: @mkrieger1 In practice, almost certainly so. But there's no guarantee. A system where `print` is implemented internally as async and could take up to 4 seconds to complete could produce these results (silly example).

Comment: That's a convincing argument.

Comment: Why ------1 comes at the end? I thought the output should be  ----0 ------1 B A. What part am I missing here?